# Apache Spark: How do I convert a Spark DataFrame to a RDD with type RDD[(Type1,Type2, ...)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example, suppose I have the DataFrame:

```
var myDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(("one",1),("two",2),("three",3))).toDF("a", "b")
```

I can convert it to a `RDD[(String, Int)]` with a map:

```
var myRDD = myDF.map(r => (r(0).asInstanceOf[String], r(1).asInstanceOf[Int]))
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe using the DF schema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using pattern matching over `Row`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

myDF.map{case Row(a: String, b: Int) => (a, b)}
```

In Spark 1.6+ you can use `Dataset` as follows:

```
myDF.as[(String, Int)].rdd
```

Comment: Ooh, that `as` function is perfect.

Comment: So would your pattern matching over `Row` be faster or safer than my `asInstanceOf` map? Or does it boil down to a fairly similar operation with cleaner syntax?

Comment: The second option I am afraid. `Row` (and `DataFrame` in general) is rather annoying when it comes to static typing. Using `Dataset` should much more efficient especially if you don't convert to RDD.

Comment: Cool. Also, is there a way to use the DF schema to determine what the types should be in the resulting tuple? All of the the necessary info is stored in the DF so it seems messy to have to state the types again.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of at this moment is mapping over schema.

Comment: How do you think that would work? I can't think of a way to loop over the schema and generate a tuple type with the types that I encounter in the middle. This loop:
`for (SF <- myDF.schema)
{
  println(SF.dataType)
}`
Prints out the data types as I go along, but how would I go about making those dataTypes I encounter into a tuple type?

Comment: I thought about using it for code generation. But is more an idea than anything else.

Comment: Please could you show me how do I achieve this `myDF.as[(String, Int)].rdd` in Java . I suppose I am unable to use an Encoder correctly.